# How to get normal number from Decimal number with javascript

Tags: javascript, calculator

I need a method that convert `0.9` to `0`, and `0.1` to `0`, In JavaScript.

Like `math.round(0.9)`

But `math.round` give me `1` and I want `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use [**`Math.floor`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), it returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number.

```js
console.log(Math.floor(0.1));
console.log(Math.floor(0.9));
```